# Checkbox are not displaying in contact form 7 wordpress plugin

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to add checkbox in contact form using contact form 7 plugin for a word press website. Please review below lines of code. I am trying to add checkbox but they are not displaying on live website. Please let me know how to resolve this. I have highlighted checkbox command in bold.

```html
<div id="container" class="rounded-corners">
        <div id="content" class="rounded-corners">
    <span style="color:#ff0000;">* = Required Information</span><hr/>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="input textarea">
                    <label> Employee First Name<span>*</span></label>
                    [text* full_name id:full-name class:text placeholder "Enter caregiver first name here"] 
                </div>
                     <div class="input textarea">
                    <label> Employee Last Name<span>*</span></label>
                    [text* full_name id:full-name class:text placeholder "Enter caregiver last name here"] 
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="field">
                <div class="input textarea">
                    <label> Missed Total Hours <span>*</span></label>
                    [text* missed_hours id:missed_hours class:text placeholder "Enter total shift hours (number only). Example: 9"] 
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="field">
                <div class="input textarea">
                    <label> Reason For Missed Time In/Out <span>*</span></label>
                
    **[checkbox* checkbox-530 use_label_element "Out Of GPS" "No Network"]**

                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="field">
    <div class="verification">
    <div class="input">
                    [submit class:button "Submit"]
    </div>
    <div class="input f-right">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>            
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is how it looks like on a live website:
[image]

Comment: if you have followed the contact form 7 documentation correctly then the issue might be caused by the website CSS. inspect the items and if you can see the checkbox input then workaround the related CSS.

Comment: Checkbox tag looks okay. So guessing it’s a CSS issue. Use your browser inspector.